# Passing an javascript array to an struts action class using ajax request in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2

I have an array `ids_arr` which is initialized with some values.
I have to pass this array and retrieve it in an Action class.

Following is My code:

Script:

```
$.get('deleteProduct',
  {

    arr_ids_fm_ajax : ids_arr
  },
  function(jsonResponse){
    alert(jsonResponse.msg);
  }
    );

}
```

Action class:

```
public class ProductDetails extends ActionSupport {

    int arr_ids_fm_ajax[];

    public int[] getArr_ids_fm_ajax() {
        return arr_ids_fm_ajax;
    }

    public void setArr_ids_fm_ajax(int[] arr_ids_fm_ajax) {
        this.arr_ids_fm_ajax = arr_ids_fm_ajax;
    }

    public String deleteProduct() {
        System.out.println(arr_ids_fm_ajax[0]); // here i want the values of my
        // passed array from ajax.

        return "success";
    }
}
```

Error at console :

```
Parameter [arr_ids_fm_ajax[]] didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!
```

Please provide a solution. Thanks for the reply in advance.

Comment: Don't you have an extra `}` in the script...?

Comment: Error is clear. Your parameter name doesn't match accepted pattern. Rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Passing array like this solved the problem.

```
data: $.param({
        arr_ids_fm_ajax: ids_arr
      }, true)
```

Comment: Even during testing I'd encourage using sane, expository variable names.